# Javascript for loop works every other time

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, iteration, nodes

So basically I'm in the middle of making a to do list to practice using pure Javascript. I do not want to use Jquery. Eventually I want to recreate this using Jquery.

My current problem is that when I run my for loop on line 43(jsfiddle) it only removes every other check box when I want all of them to be toggled on and off. Sorry if my code is confusing to understand. This is my first attempt at creating something this complicated.

```
function editItem() {
var findSpanBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("spanBox");
var findTextBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("list-item");
var btnDelete = document.createElement("span");
var btnSave = document.getElementsByClassName("save");
if (btnSave.length >= 1) {
    alert("Please save all items first.");
} else if (clicked == 0) {
    clicked = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < findSpanBoxes.length; i++) {
        findSpanBoxes[i].innerHTML = '<input class="box" type="checkbox"></input>';
        btnDelete.innerHTML = '<button class="button">Delete</button>';
        // findTextBoxes[i].appendChild(btnDelete);
    }
} else {
    clicked = 0;
    debugger;
    // **** Problem *****
    for (x = 0; x < findSpanBoxes.length; x++) {
        var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[x];
        box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
        console.log(x);
    }
}
}
```

To see my problem add a few items, save each, then click edit a few times.

http://jsfiddle.net/whsn1bom/31/

Please leave any suggestions / comments!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Because when you remove the item the other items shift down one. It is a live collection. Loop backwards or use while loop.

```
for (var x = findSpanBoxes.length-1 x>=0; x--) {
```

or

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
while (boxes.length) {
    var box = boxes[0];
    box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic flaw on this line

```
for (x = 0; x < findSpanBoxes.length; x++) {
```

Change the iteration to the following, and it will work

```
for (x = findSpanBoxes.length-1; x >=0; x--) {
```

This is because when you remove the child item item from the list, the index of each element decrements by one.  By removing items from the end of the list (i.e. at the highest index), the indecies of the remaining items does not change.

For example, say you have items `(index 0 = A, index 1 = B; index 3 = C; index 4 = D).`

- The first loop (x=0) removes item 0 (A) and the new list becomes `(index 0 = B, index 1 = C; index 2 = D)`. The removal of the first element has caused the indecies of the remaining items to change.
- The first loop (x=1) removes item 1 which is C.  Note that B is skipped because its index has changed from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your console for errors?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
```

The problem is that you're calling `document.getElementsByClassName("box")` inside your loop. Why is this an issue? Well, you're removing the items inside the loop as well. Every time you remove an item, the `document.getElementsByClassName("box")` array is getting shorter, because it's only returning items that exist at the time of execution (and you're removing items between your calls).

To help explain this, think about it this way. The first time through your loop, you remove the first **index** of `.box`. Then, on the next iteration, you're making a new array, and you're removing the **second** index. Therefore, you've just skipped a box.

So, to fix this, you could just always remove the first index of the array.

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
```

Alternatively, you could get the parent objects, and remove the `.box` element that way.

```
var box_parent = document.getElementsByClassName("spanBox")[x];
box_parent.removeChild(box_parent.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

As [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)'s answer implied, [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is a live collection; changes to the DOM are automatically and immediately reflected in it.

As his answer says, iterating over the array backwards avoids the side effects of removing items from the DOM. Another solution would be to [convert the array-like HTMLCollection into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects):

```
var boxes = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("box"));
```

This would make `boxes` a real array instead of a live array-like object. Updates to the DOM will not change the length of the array, thus you can still iterate over the array forwards.

If you are using a transpiler or only targeting ES6 capable browsers you could use the spread operator to shorten the array conversion to:

```
var boxes = [...document.getElementsByClassName("box")];
```